# Calling localhost project on different machine like www.example.com

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

i have installed XAMPP, but i would like to run my localhost from another computer now my url is `localhost:8080/manage/manage/login` and i want to change it `www.tracker.com` using xampp itself and access it using other machines..I am totally fresher i don't know more about this.Please help me.

Comment: https://sg.godaddy.com/ :P

Comment: if your 8080 port is publicly accessible (in LAN)  then on your other PC you can try your local IP (something like 192.168.0.XX) and then call that url from other PC.  (192.168.0.XX:8080/manage/manage/login)

Comment: Search on google url - rewriting and if you want globally then you need to buy a domain